# Creating Method Adapter using ASM 4.0 (Java bytecode library)

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

1. Has anyone got a link to some example ASM code (java byte code library) for creating a method adapter? (The return type and arguments of the method being adapted are not known until runtime)
2. Do you think the modification shown below is possible with ASM?

The following code:

```
public Blah doBling( Bling bling ){

Blah blah = doSomething( bling );
    return blah;
}
```

gets modified into the following code using a java agent:

```
private Blah _doBling( Bling bling ){

     Blah blah = doSomething( bling );
     return blah;
}

public Blah doBling( Bling bling ){

    if ( Mode.recordMode() ){

        Blah blah = _doBling( bling );
        Mode.record( blah );
        return blah;
    }
    else {
        Blah blah = Mode.playback( bling );
        return blah;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the [User Guide](http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf), it has everything you need. Also, using `ASMifier` would simplify your task.

Comment: And, yes it is perfectly possible with ASM.